# How to modify the image color after two images

Tags: opencv

I have two face images. I can map one face images onto the other one.
However, the generated image is not good. How can I refined the color and
light on the face region ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a [histogram match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching) to the original face. You wont be able to recreate the shadow effects that way, but you might be able to match the skin tone.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this links will be helpful:

1) Image [recoloring](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/06/24/image-recoloring-using-gaussian-mixture-model-and-expectation-maximization-opencv-wcode/)

2) Face [relighting](http://cg.skeelogy.com/face-image-relighting/)

Comment: it do helps. Thx a lot . Especially, the image recoloring could help me to recolor the hair image.